# Disable Woocommerce "proceed to checkout" button and change CSS if minimum order is not met

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a plugin - Order Minimum/Maximum Amount for WooCommerce - which is a pretty good plugin, except that it just puts a redirect on the "proceed to checkout" to reload the cart until the customer has added enough to meet the minimum dollar amount. It's a bad user experience.

I found the following that takes care of disabling the button, but fixing the css so the button appears greyed out is my missing piece.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('body.woocommerce-cart').on('click', '.wc-proceed-to-checkout', function(event){
        if (jQuery('.woocommerce-error').length > 0) {
            event.preventDefault();
        
    }
```

I'd like to ditch this jQUery and do the disable and css change with a function. The plugin part that does the redirect is this:

```
function block_checkout( $wp ) {
    if ( ! is_checkout() || ! apply_filters( 'alg_wc_oma_block_checkout', true ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $result = $this->messages->get_notices( 'cart' );
    if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( version_compare( get_option( 'woocommerce_version', null ), '2.5.0', '<' ) ? WC()->cart->get_cart_url() : wc_get_cart_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Thanks y'all!

Comment: The part that does the redirect, isn't directly relevant for what you want here - that gets executed, when the user _has_ already pressed the button. It has nothing whatsoever to do with the _creation_ of that button. You need to find the place in your template where that button is created, and apply the `alg_wc_oma_block_checkout` filter there, to see whether a checkout should be allowed at this point based on the current cart contents, or not.

Comment: Thanks. After doing a bit more digging what would satisfy the requirement  is to change the style of the checkout button if there's an error in the cart so there's visual cue to the user before they click the button and experience the confusion of the cart page just reloading.

Comment: Something like `$(this).prop('disabled', true);` inside the click handler should probably do?